# Changing the location hash of a parent window & running a script afterward

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a small personal website, and for a main part of the navigation, I'd like to use location hashes. I have a link on a page embedded in an iframe that I would like to be able to change the location hash of the parent page, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want.

To be more specific, I *can* get it to work if I ONLY want to change the location hash, but I also want to run a script on the parent window to check the hash after it has been changed. Here is what I did for only changing the hash:

```html
<a href="../#foobar" target="_parent">Click Me!</a>
```

And this is what I've *tried*, to make it run a function afterward:

```html
<a onclick='parent.location.hash="foobar";parent.theFunction();' href="#" >Click Me!</a>
```

When trying this, it doesn't even seem to change the hash in the first place, which makes me think there's some other way of having it change the parent hash via JS that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I ended up finding out that the `hashchange` event exists.

For anyone else looking to do a similar thing, here's how you'd do it:

```js
window.addEventListener("hashchange", yourFunction)

function yourFunction() {
    // do stuff
}
```

in your parent page - the listener will run the function `yourFunction` whenever the page hash changes.